# AnalyzeDocumentAsync (Azure Document Intelligence) is throwing a 404 exception

Tags: .net, azure, artificial-intelligence, azure-form-recognizer

I have the following code:

```
public async Task TestExtractionDataAsync()
{
    _documentAnalysisClient = new DocumentIntelligenceClient(new Uri(endpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(key));

    var documentUri = new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample-invoice.pdf");

    var analyzeDocumentContent = new AnalyzeDocumentContent()
{
    UrlSource = documentUri 
};

    var operation = await _documentAnalysisClient.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, "Test_6_Jornalera", analyzeDocumentContent);
}
```

And the method 'AnalyzeDocumentAsync' is throwing a '404 Not Found' exception. The file url is valid. The endpoint and the key are the sames from here:
[Key and endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsm8d.png)

And from the ModelId is extracted from here:
[Models Ids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNWmh.png)

One thing I noticed is that in the Document Intelligence section in Azure AI my project doesn't appear:
[DIS section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLbfI.png)

I created the Document Intelligence project from here:
[Created in 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W305H.png)
[Created in 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuNwA.png)

Any ideas of what could be happening? I don't know why the method throws a 404. All the elements, urls and keys are on place.

I tried the documentation step by steps but it seems to be obsolete ([Use Document Intelligence models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/how-to-guides/use-sdk-rest-api?view=doc-intel-4.0.0&tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-csharp)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas of what could be happening? I don't know why the method throws a 404. All the elements, urls and keys are on place.

Here I have created an [application](https://i.imgur.com/VLRXn3c.png) to interact with the Azure Form Recognizer service.

**FormRecognizerService.cs:**

```cs
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer;
using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.Models;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyFormRecognizerApp
{
    public class FormRecognizerService
    {
        private readonly FormRecognizerClient _formRecognizerClient;

        public FormRecognizerService(string endpoint, string key)
        {
            var credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key);
            _formRecognizerClient = new FormRecognizerClient(new Uri(endpoint), credential);
        }

        public async Task AnalyzeDocumentAsync(Uri documentUri, string modelName)
        {
            try
            {
                // Start the custom form recognition operation
                RecognizeCustomFormsOperation operation = await _formRecognizerClient.StartRecognizeCustomFormsFromUriAsync(modelName, documentUri);

                // Wait for the operation to complete
                await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();

                // Get the response
                Response<RecognizedFormCollection> response = await operation.WaitForCompletionAsync();

                // Check if the operation was successful
                if (response.GetRawResponse().Status == 200)
                {
                    RecognizedFormCollection recognizedForms = response.Value;
                    // Process the recognized forms
                    foreach (RecognizedForm form in recognizedForms)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Form of type: {form.FormType}");
                        foreach (FormField field in form.Fields.Values)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"INVOICE: {form.Fields["INVOICE"].Value}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"DATE: {form.Fields["DATE"].Value}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new RequestFailedException("The operation did not complete successfully.");
                }
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error analyzing document: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyFormRecognizerApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string endpoint = "https://your-Document intelligence.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
            string key = "key";
            string modelName = "modelID";

            var service = new FormRecognizerService(endpoint, key);

            Uri documentUri = new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample-invoice.pdf\r\n");

            await service.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(documentUri, modelName);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Document intelligence resource.
[image]

- Below is my model by taking a sample invoice to test and I have trained.

[image]

- Here my task is to analyse the document and get the below fields recognise and should be print in the console.

[image]

[image]

Comment: With the FormRecognizer nuget it works perfectly. The problem is with the new DocumentIntelligence nuget. It looks like it's not ready to use.